# не работает функция JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы функция возвращала `false` если в `password` найдено одно из значений `linesArray`, чтобы цикл проверял каждое значение массива, но почему что не работает, не пойму почему.

```js
var linesArray = ["abcd","efg", "hrh"];
var password = "213efg123"
var resultat = true;
var testValidity = function(){
    for (i = 0;resultat = true; i++) {
  let arr = linesArray[i];
  let str = password;
  let test = str.indexOf(arr.toString());
      if (test > -1) {
        resultat = false
      }
      return resultat;
    }
};
```

Comment: `resultat = true` - опечатка, должно было быть `==`

Comment: @Grundy там проблема в том, что `return` прерывает цикл на первой итерации, а `resultat = false` - просто присвоение значения переменной, там нет опечатки.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, очевидно есть, потому что если убрать return - цикл становится бесконечным

Comment: @Grundy, да, пожалуй, соглашусь, поспешил с выводом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ещё один фидл

```js
var LinesArray = ["abcd","efg", "hrh"],
 password = "213efg123",
 testValidity = function(){
  var resultat = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < LinesArray.length; i++) {
   var reg = new RegExp(LinesArray[i]);
   if(reg.test(password)){
    resultat = false;
    break;
   }
      }
      return resultat;
    };
console.log(testValidity());
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас было три ошибки в коде, в первой строке

> var LinesArray["abcd","efg", "hrh"];

не было знака `равно`.

А в функции вы использовали обращение к массиву `linesArray[i]`, тогда как у вас переменная называлась `LinesArray` (с большой буквы).

А также у вас получается `return` вызывался при первой итерации цикла, в результате цикл прерывался и вы не доходили до следующих значений. Проще всего вынести `return` за пределы цикла `for`.

И, по-моему, лучше ограничить цикл `for` длинной массива `linesArray`.

```js
var linesArray = ["abcd", "efg", "hrh"];
var password = "213efg123"
var resultat = true;
var testValidity = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {
    let arr = linesArray[i];
    let str = password;
    let test = str.indexOf(arr.toString());
    if (test > -1) {
      resultat = false
      break;
    }
  }
  return resultat; //перенос return
};

console.log(testValidity());
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут ошибка: `var LinesArray["abcd","efg", "hrh"];`, должно быть `var LinesArray = ["abcd","efg", "hrh"];`

И тут ошибка: `let arr = linesArray[i]` - вместо определенной ранее переменной "LinesArray" прописана неизвестная "linesArray". Javascript чувствителен к регистру.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var linesArray = ["abcd", "efg", "hrh"];
var password = "213efg123"
var testValidity = function(pwd, lines) {
  return !lines.some(line => pwd.indexOf(line) > -1);
}

console.log(testValidity(password, linesArray));
```